# What is <classifier> in <configuration> in maven

Tags: maven-plugin

what is the use of classifier tag in  inside configuration tag in maven.
example:
        
          org.apache.maven.plugins
          maven-jar-plugin
          2.2
          
            
              pre-process-classes
              compile
              
                jar
              
              
                pre-process

Answer (score 2):

LMGTFY:

> classifier:\ The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were
>   built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some
>   optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the
>   artifact name just after the version number.
>
> As a motivation for this element, consider for example a project that
>   offers an artifact targeting JRE 1.5 but at the same time also an
>   artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be
>   equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the second one with jdk14 such
>   that clients can choose which one to use.
>
> Another common use case for classifiers is the need to attach
>   secondary artifacts to the project’s main artifact. If you browse the
>   Maven central repository, you will notice that the classifiers sources
>   and javadoc are used to deploy the project source code and API docs
>   along with the packaged class files.

Comment: thanks for reply.In the above example in <classifier>I didn't mentioned any version. how it works? Can you please clarify me.